# How to open popup windows in background using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to open pop-up windows BEHIND the current active screen using java script?

```
 var win= window.open(value,'_blank');
```

the above script opens pop windows in browser tab but I loss active page from my sight.

any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Solution:

As per **@Brian** advised,

```
var win=window.open(value,null,"height=400,width=600,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no");
win.blur();
```

Its works in IE,FireFox and safari but **not in Chrome browser**.

**Can any one suggest how to open multiple popup boxes in IE browser?** The above script will open only one pop up in IE.

Comment: sounds shady .. what is this for ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add:

```
win.blur();
```

... to your code ...

Or

```
this.window.focus();
```

Comment: Note - although this may sometimes work, some browsers now have default settings to prevent this. Firefox for example has a setting pre-set to not allow JavaScript to raise and lower windows.  I can only imagine it was added to precisely stop the behavior of launching "pop under" windows. screenshot: http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/2051/capture07272011064930.png

Comment: @Sunliffe - nice ref - I should definitely have included the caveat that you're at the mercy of today's helpful anti-annoyance features included in most browsers :)

Comment: Thank you Brian, its works for IE8, Firefox (after enable javascript) , Safari but not in chrome browser. Can you help me for chrome browser?

Comment: Actually I don't have chrome installed on this box ...  if I can remember to I'll give it a shot on a box w/ chrome tonight...  if someone else doesn't chime in first...

Answer (score 3):

+1 to Brian's answer to refocus the original window afterwards. If you, for some reason, *always* want it to be behind, you can use the `alwaysLowered` property:

> **alwaysLowered**
>   If set to yes, the new created window floats below, under its own parent when the parent window is not minimized. alwaysLowered windows are often referred as pop-under windows. The alwaysLowered window can not be on top of the parent but the parent window can be minimized. In NS 6.x, the alwaysLowered window has no minimize system command icon and no restore/maximize system command.

Good documentation of all the available features can be found on the MDC [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open) page.

Comment: alwaysLowered seems not working any more

Answer (score 1):

I found that with Firefox it was not possible to push the window to the back, no matter how much of the code I modified. Ultimately I settled for making the window small enough 10, 10 so that it appeared in one of the corners and was barely perceived by the visitor.

```
var win=window.open(value,null,"height=10,width=10,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no");
```

Chrome opens the popup/under in a tab and iE does place it in the background, behind the active window.

Answer (score 1):

For *more cross-browser solution* I'd suggest to take a look at this script — [jquery-popunder](https://github.com/hpbuniat/jquery-popunder):

> **...was tested with:**
>
> - Mozilla Firefox 3-19
> - Google Chrome 10-25
>
>   - Note: Currently you can only create 2 popunder in Chrome 22-24
>   - Note: In Chrome 23-24 you'll need a separate event for the popunder-effect (see the examples!)
> - Microsoft Internet Explorer 6-9
> - Apple Safari 5
>
>   **Known issues:**
> - the script does not work with the Opera-Browser, so the opera-browser    is disable by default
> - the script does not work in Firefox under Gnome
> - in Firefox, when the setting: 'Open new windows in a new tab instead'    is deactivated

Note that

> *This script will only work, if the popunder is opened
>   on a user-generated event (e.g. click or submit).*