# Open a window behind the current window not work in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

I have open a window behiend the current window it work fine in i.E10 but not work in chrome  and firefox .My code given below please review and give me a solution.

**Parent window HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function openPopUP() {
  window.open('hidden.html','NewWin',
            'toolbar=no,status=no,width=350,height=135')
}
</script></head>

<body onLoad="openPopUP();">
<!--// <a href="javascript:hide();">Click</a> to open a small hidden window.-->
</body>
</html>
```

**Child Winow i.e PopUp Window File code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body onLoad="window.parent.opener.focus(); " 
        >

          window is open
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are no good reasons to use popunders.

Comment: why do you want to do this? firefox and chrome prevent this! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842892/how-to-open-popup-windows-in-background-using-javascript

Comment: @mplungjan this will not work anymore

Comment: Good. I am happy to hear it :)