# Javascript pop under window (Background window)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I'm to open pop-up windows BEHIND the current active screen using java script.
Here is my simple code.

```
var win = window.open('http://yahoo.com',null,"height=400,width=600,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes");
win.blur();
this.window.focus();
```

But it doesn't seems to be work in any browser. It simply opens a pop up.I referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842892/how-to-open-popup-windows-in-background-using-javascript) from stackoverflow. But it doesn't work. My aim is to create a background window in all browsers. Someone help me please

Comment: which browser are you testing this on?

Comment: Are you really trying to open yahoo or is the child window yours as well?

Comment: You can no more reproduce this kind of behaviour, not in all browsers. People are tired about that... Your best bet was https://github.com/tuki/js-popunder

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this. Modern web browsers do not allow websites to steal the focus from other tabs (because this could become quite messy for the users). The only thing that you could do is prompt your users to open in a new tab (which does not change the focus). Or you can abuse an alert to get the focus back to your page:

```
var win =   window.open('http://yahoo.com',null,"target=_blank,height=400,width=600,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes");
alert("Welcome back");
```

Comment: How do I achieve this. I need to create background window

Comment: @ling.s alert() should bring focus on main window but afaik, not cross browser

Comment: @ling.s Looks like you don't read all comments or don't want to understand what's going on...

Comment: I understand.. I'm asking if anyother methods are there? If it is not possible, then how so many sites open pop under?

Comment: @ling.s most use https://github.com/tuki/js-popunder Now if you have any link which works on chrome, please provide it? BTW, if you know this kind of sites, why don't you check source?

Answer (score -1):

```
function makePopunder(pUrl) {
var _parent = (top != self && typeof (top["document"]["location"].toString()) === "string") ? top : self;
var mypopunder = null;
var pName = (Math["floor"]((Math["random"]() * 1000) + 1));
var pWidth = window["innerWidth"];
var pHeight = window["innerHeight"];
var pPosX = window["screenX"];
var pPosY = window["screenY"];
var pWait = 3600;
pWait = (pWait * 1000);
var pCap = 50000;
var todayPops = 0;
var cookie = "_.mypopunder";
var browser = function () {
    var n = navigator["userAgent"]["toLowerCase"]();
    var b = {
        webkit: /webkit/ ["test"](n),
        mozilla: (/mozilla/ ["test"](n)) && (!/(compatible|webkit)/ ["test"](n)),
        chrome: /chrome/ ["test"](n),
        msie: (/msie/ ["test"](n)) && (!/opera/ ["test"](n)),
        firefox: /firefox/ ["test"](n),
        safari: (/safari/ ["test"](n) && !(/chrome/ ["test"](n))),
        opera: /opera/ ["test"](n)
    };
    b["version"] = (b["safari"]) ? (n["match"](/.+(?:ri)[\\/: ]([\\d.]+)/) || [])[1] : (n["match"](/.+(?:ox|me|ra|ie)[\\/: ]([\\d.]+)/) || [])[1];
    return b;
}();

function isCapped() {
    try {
        todayPops = Math["floor"](document["cookie"]["split"](cookie + "Cap=")[1]["split"](";")[0]);
    } catch (err) {};
    return (pCap <= todayPops || document["cookie"]["indexOf"](cookie + "=") !== -1);
};

function doPopunder(pUrl, pName, pWidth, pHeight, pPosX, pPosY) {
    if (isCapped()) {
        return;
    };
    var sOptions = "toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=yes,statusbar=yes,menubar=no,resizable=1,width=" + pWidth.toString() + ",height=" + pHeight.toString() + ",screenX=" + pPosX + ",screenY=" + pPosY;
    document["onclick"] = function (e) {
        if (isCapped() || window["pop_clicked"] == 1 || pop_isRightButtonClicked(e)) {
            //return;
        };
        window["pop_clicked"] = 1;
        mypopunder = _parent["window"]["open"](pUrl, pName, sOptions);
        if (mypopunder) {
            var now = new Date();
            document["cookie"] = cookie + "=1;expires=" + new Date(now["setTime"](now["getTime"]() + pWait))["toGMTString"]() + ";path=/";
            now = new Date();
            document["cookie"] = cookie + "Cap=" + (todayPops + 1) + ";expires=" + new Date(now["setTime"](now["getTime"]() + (84600 * 1000)))["toGMTString"]() + ";path=/";
            pop2under();
        };
    };
};

function pop2under() {
    try {
        mypopunder["blur"]();
        mypopunder["opener"]["window"]["focus"]();
        window["self"]["window"]["blur"]();
        window["focus"]();
        if (browser["firefox"]) {
            openCloseWindow();
        };
        if (browser["webkit"]) {
            openCloseTab();
        };
    } catch (e) {};
};

function openCloseWindow() {
    var ghost = window["open"]("about:blank");
    ghost["focus"]();
    ghost["close"]();
};

function openCloseTab() {
    var ghost = document["createElement"]("a");
    ghost["href"] = "about:blank";
    ghost["target"] = "PopHelper";
    document["getElementsByTagName"]("body")[0]["appendChild"](ghost);
    ghost["parentNode"]["removeChild"](ghost);
    var clk = document["createEvent"]("MouseEvents");
    clk["initMouseEvent"]("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
    ghost["dispatchEvent"](clk);
    window["open"]("about:blank", "PopHelper")["close"]();
};

function pop_isRightButtonClicked(e) {
    var rightclick = false;
    e = e || window["event"];
    if (e["which"]) {
        rightclick = (e["which"] == 3);
    } else {
        if (e["button"]) {
            rightclick = (e["button"] == 2);
        };
    };
    return rightclick;
};
if (isCapped()) {
    return;
} else {
    doPopunder(pUrl, pName, pWidth, pHeight, pPosX, pPosY);
};
```

}

makePopunder("http://www.yourdomain.com/");